# best api call for updating tags of an object

Tags: database, api, rest

It is a simple matter, but it got me curious.
I have a tags table with `video_id` and `tag` columns (people can create any tags).
Let's say a user wants to update the tags of one of their videos.
 
He will call an api and send the list of his new tags, and on the server side these tags will be checked. All tags that disappeared will be deleted from the table and all the new tags will be stored in their place. 
Now the most obvious api call I can think of is PUT, however from the database viewpoint I am calling a POST/DELETE api, so it doesn't feel quite right. 
Any api is probably gonna work just fine, but which is the one I should be using?

Comment: I would use a PUT as you suggested.  A PUT request is to be idempotent, meaning that if the user submits the same exact request multiple times, you will have the same single over arching result in the database.  However a POST is not to be idempotent, this means with many video request tags for the same user/video id, then the tags would be repeated in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to close the question! 
As mentioned by @EspressoBeans it is ideal to use a PUT request for case scenarios like this.

Thanks!